# How to capture if checkbox is checked or unchecked

Tags: jquery

I have a table and in each column it has a checkbox which has a class but no id or name. When the checkbox is checked or unchecked I am showing the checkbox state using an `alert()`:

```
$(document).on('change', '[class*="box"]', function () {
    var tableRow = $(this).closest('tr');
    alert('check state ' + $("[class*='box']").is(':checked') ? 1 : 0);    
});
```

My `alert()` always returns `1` whether the checkbox is checked or unchecked. Maybe my coding approach could be wrong. Can anyone help to get the right state of checkbox? Thanks

Comment: You can use `CheckboxElement.checked`.

Comment: only use `$(".box")` i think problem with brackets. and do `(($(this).is(':checked')) ? 1 : 0)`

Comment: Use `$(this).is(':checked')` instead

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Check checkbox checked property](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/901712/check-checkbox-checked-property)

Comment: You are evaluating in ternary operator `'check state ' + $("[class*='box']").is(':checked')` which is string concatenation and in this case is always thruthly, so always returning `1`. It should be obvious regarding your returning alert() result that the string part `check state` was missing...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use `this`:

```
$(document).on('change', '[class*="box"]', function () {
    var tableRow = $(this).closest('tr');
    alert('check state ' + ((this.checked) ? 1 : 0));
});
```

Also ternary conditions need extra brackets for better functioning.